# Mustache templates: How to output a block only once for non-empty lists

Tags: mustache

If my list is empty, I want to output this:

```html
<div id="some-id">
</div>
```

If my list is non-empty, I want to output this:

```html
<div id="some-id">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>etc</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note that I output the `<ul>` and `</ul>` tags *at most once*, and only if the list is non-empty.

The following code is close to how I would do this in PHP, but is obviously wrong:

```html
<div id="some-id">
{{#items}}
  <ul>
{{/items}}

{{#items}}
    <li>{{name}}</li>
{{/items}}

{{#items}}
  </ul>
{{/items}}
</div>
```

If `items` is a 3 item list, I'm going to get 3 `<ul>`'s - obviously not what I want.

I realise I could set some other key as a boolean flag (`hasItems`, perhaps), but this feels redundant.

Is there a more elegant way I can output a block only once for a non-empty list?

Comment: In my opinion (and 4 years later) there is still no satisfying solution for this problem in "mustache" afaik. we would need the opposite of an "inverted section" - a section that renders **only once** if the key's value is truthy (key exists, non-empty list, key value is true,...) !

Comment: The key value is displayed whether it is exists in the context. If the value(string) have more than 10 characters, i  don't want to display it. Shall i achieve this ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [non-false values](http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html) of a section. `name` would have to be an object inside of `items`

```
data = { 'items' : { 'name' : ["Item 1", "Item 2", "etc"] } };
```

You template would look like:

```
<div id="some-id">
    {{#items}}
    <ul>
        {{#name}}
        <li>{{.}}</li>
        {{/name}}
    </ul>
    {{/items}}
</div>
```

Here's an example on jsFiddle showing the rendering of an `items` object with names and without -- http://jsfiddle.net/maxbeatty/fpQwk/

Comment: Hmmm.  That's an interesting idea.  I'd probably represent the data as `{ 'itemsContainer' : { 'items' : [ { 'name' : 'item 1' }, { 'name' : 'item 2' }, { 'name' : 'etc' } ] } };`.  Thanks!

Comment: having to change data structure only because the template rendiring doesn't support the specific case seems to me very limiting.

Comment: if you don't want to change your data structure, change your template engine

Answer (score 18):

If you don't want to or can't reformat your data or templating engine, you can also just check `items.length` before rendering the `<ul>` tags. Some people frown upon this, but it's definitely an alternative to Max's answer.

```
{{#items.length}}
    <ul>
        {{items}}
            <li>{{name}}</li>
        {{/items}}
    </ul>
{{/items.length}}
```

Comment: Nice.  That'd only work with a JavaScript implementation of JavaScript, though, right?

Comment: yea, but most languages have some sort of property or method that you can check to get the length of the array... with java, it's `.size`, etc. So it _should_ translate to most languages.

Comment: I'm using the [PHP version of Mustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php) which has a [count function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php), not property or method.  However, I just tried this with an [ArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) and `{{#items.count}}` works as expected.  Which is great.  Thanks!

Comment: Having this functionality language-dependent is only a bit better than having to change model structure to fit into view

Comment: How to get the name key and modify its value before rendering??? Any possibilities to set the value of name key in to new variable??

Answer (score 1):

The other two answers do not work for the Ruby implementation of Mustache. My solution was to send an additional parameter as part of the template context; e.g.

```rb
template = <<EOF
{{#has_items}}
<ul>
    {{#items}}
        <li>{{.}}</li>
    {{/items}}
</ul>
{{/has_items}}
EOF
items = ['one', 'two', 'three']
context = { items: items, has_items: items.any? }
Mustache.render(template, context)
```