# Mustache render list if not empty

Tags: mustache

I would like to use Moustache to render an HTML unordered list only if a list object is not empty. So I would like:

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
```

if the list has elements and *nothing* if the list is empty (not even ul tags)

How can I do this?

edit: my data structure is:

```
{ "list": ["first item", "second item"] }
```

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102931/mustache-templates-how-to-output-a-block-only-once-for-non-empty-lists/10118092#10118092

Comment: That is an interesting approach, but I was hoping there is a way to do this without modifying my data structure

Comment: Could you add your data structure to your question?

Comment: could be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653764/mustache-how-to-detect-array-is-not-empty

Answer (score 26):

If you don't want to or can't reformat your data, you can also just check `items.length` before rendering the `<ul>` tags. Some people frown upon this, but it's definitely an alternative to Mike's answer.

```
{{#items.length}}
    <ul>
        {{items}}
            <li>{{property}}</li>
        {{/items}}
    </ul>
{{/items.length}}
```

Comment: Or .size if you are using the Java version

Comment: I'm using someone else's api and can't change it. `.length` works for me.

Comment: Just tried this solution on http://trymustache.com/ and I get the following error: Mustache error:
Unclosed section "items.length" at 87

Comment: @broox you are missing a '#',  `{{#items}}`

Comment: As pointed out in [stackoverflow.com/questions/11653764](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653764/mustache-how-to-detect-array-is-not-empty), `{{#items.0}}...{{/items.0}}{{^items.0}}...{{/items.0}}` might do a better job.

Comment: The `{{items.0}}` worked for me. `{{items.length}}` didn't even render the template

Answer (score 10):

You need to reformat your data structure to this:

```
{
    "list": {
        "items": ["first item", "second item"]
    }
}
```

Your Mustache template would now be this

```
{{#list}}
    <ul>
        {{#items}}
            <li>{{.}}</li>
        {{/items}}
    </ul>
{{/list}}
```

I made a video explaining how Mustache works, and how to implement it using both PHP and JavaScript.  You can find it here: http://mikemclin.net/mustache-templates-for-php-and-javascript/

Comment: It seems kind of unreasonable to ask people to reformat their data structures to accommodate a templating language.

Comment: I agree.  That's why I personally would choose a different template language.  However, if you want to use Mustache, this is how.  I like brook's solution better, but I am not sure that the `length` property is always available.  I think it might be an enhancement added by the Javascript implementation. I was unable to find any mention of it in the Mustache Manual: https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html.

Comment: It is relatively easy to create a model for the template, deroved from your data stricture but modified as required. This has the advantage that the transformation is performed in code in an actual programming language that is easy to debug.

Comment: Complex logic in e.g. Thymeleaf or Angular is exactly what made people yearn something clean and simple. I ageee, though, that pseudovalues "first" and "last" for list elements should be easy to include without making Mustache yet another Velocity or JSP.