# php mustache conditional value like handlebars block helpers

Tags: php, mustache, handlebars.js, mustache.php

In Handlebars, you can make conditionals, like:

```
{{#if isActive}}
  <img src="star.gif" alt="Active">
{{/if}}
```

http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html

I've been trying for a while to do something like this in the PHP Mustache. But nowhere i can find anything allowing {{#something withvalue }}

Why not just use the {{#each }} to `if` something? If I want to Each over a list making `li`s, and I only want to wrap them in a `ul` when there are actually `li`s?

I would need an extra value that has prechecked the list, which I think is ugly.

```
{{#hasList }}
<ul>
{{# list }}
    <li>{{ title }}</li>
{{/ list }}
</ul>
{{/hasList }}
```

There must be a way to handle this in Mustache, right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10118092/4036946

Comment: It's not ugly, it's Mustache. Each implementation has its own way to escape this feature paucity, and it looks like you can use the .count property of PHP arrays, as in {{#list.count}}<ul>...</ul>{{/list.count}}: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19427289/525656

Comment: `{{#list.count}}` only works if you have an `ArrayIterator` wrapping your array. You can fake it with a `{{#list.0}}` section tag, but in my opinion that's much uglier than adding the extra value.

Comment: `.count` has worked for me with an `new ArrayObject`. Thanks!